# What is it output sensitive algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, 3d, computer-science, raytracing

What of this algorithms is output sensitive ? (their base algorithm)

1. ray tracing
2. gpu rendering
3. splatting

How can we make them with acceleration method to be likely output sensitive ?

I think ray tracing and gpu is not output sensitive.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what of this algorithms i mentioned is output sensitive?

Answer (score 3):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Output-sensitive_algorithm

For the folks who didn't understand the question, *in computer science, an output-sensitive algorithm is an algorithm whose running time depends on the size of the output, instead of or in addition to the size of the input.*

**Ray Tracing** is output sensitive, in fact many ray tracing programs can generate smaller size images or movies in faser time.

**GPU rendering** is output sensitive, the fact that the GPU can parallelise the task, can speed up, but far less computations are required to render a smaller size image than a bigger one.

**Texture splatting**, is also output sensitive, since typically textures are repeated, so you can generate a huge image joining many of them, thus requiring more cpu power (and memory).

Comment: Is ray tracing and gpu rendering in their basic algorithms are output sensitive ?? ( without acceleration methods )